# fade out old element, fade in new

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

I am new to react and have tried [react animations](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html). They work great when elements are added or removed in a TransitionGroup. But if I replace a single element with a similar one, react detects that the content of that element has changed and does not trigger an animation.

How can I fade out a single element and fade in a new one in the same place?
For example  fade out login-div, fade in dashboard-div.

Comment: did u tried jquery animation on elements how its behave ? Can u provide some fiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your elements have different `key` attributes, TransitionGroup will unmount one and mount the other.

You can read more about keys here: [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#dynamic-children).