# Reactjs animate replace: How to wait for fade out before adding content to fade in?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, reactjs

I am trying to use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` to replace content by fading out some content, waiting for it to disappear completely, and then fading in new content.

I am using `key` props which was the solution to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21875208/1379290), so the content is being swapped out and animated. The problem, though, is that the new content is added to the DOM and takes up space in the flow from the start, rather that waiting until the old content has faded out. i.e., I can delay fading in with a transition delay, but the gap where the content will fade in is there from the start. Since CSS `visibility:hidden` still adds space for the element in the flow using that with `opacity` doesn't help either.

**My question:** Is there a way to achieve the desired outcome using only CSS? If not, I presume my component will have to detect the end of the fade-out transition and only then add the new element; what is the recommended React way for detecting and reacting to `transitionend` events?

My code thus far:

```
// jsx

let key = this.state.adding ? 'addForm' : 'addPlaceholder';

<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="fade">
  <div key={key}>
    {this.state.adding ? this.renderForm() : this.renderPlaceholder()}
  </div>
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>


// css

.fade-enter {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.01;
}
.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in .3s;
}

.fade-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-leave.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the **[Low-level API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup)**? I think this could be something that can be used.

Comment: @TahirAhmed As far as I can tell the low-level API triggers callbacks on the children being added/removed, but does not inform the parent. Since the same logic could en up duplicated in various children I'd prefer to keep it in the parent if that turns out to be possible. Otherwise using a single fade-wrapper for various child components might be an option.

Comment: but I suppose you can pass some inner function of parent to the child via `props`, this way I think the child can call parent method to inform that it is done?

Comment: @TahirAhmed From what I can tell the animation life-cycle methods such as `componentWillEnter` should be class methods and not methods on the `props`. This means I'll still need an animation aware child with these life-cycle methods calling the parent method passed on the `props`. It can certainly be done with a fade-wrapper component around all children. If, however, this could be handled without wrapping the children that will be a bonus.

Comment: I am not too sure. Is it possible for you to come up with a simple jsFiddle? You can use one from the [getting started](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would seem there is no way to achieve the desired outcome using only CSS.

Since `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` intercepts the low-level API animation life-cycle methods there is no way detect the end of an animation when using it. The only remaining avenue is using the low-level API of `ReactTransitionGroup` directly.

By wrapping children in a component that informs the parent container when the life-cycle methods are called the parent can delay adding a new component to its children until it is informed that the transition of the leaving child has completed.

I have published the [`react-css-transition-replace` component](https://github.com/marnusw/react-css-transition-replace), which implements this, on GitHub/`npm` under the MIT license.

Answer (score 1):

I have published a component, [`fade-props`](https://github.com/chipit24/fade-props), which addresses this problem specifically.

Under "Rendering a Single Child", the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#rendering-a-single-child) say "*This approach wouldn't work when animating multiple children or replacing the single child with another child*"; so what you are tyring to do would be tricky with the available API.